# Mysql schema keeps dropping tables without action

Tags: mysql, database, spring, mysql-workbench

Every time i relog to mysqlworkbench the tables that i have created within my schema have been automatically dropped. This happens after about 2 hours every time. I can't quite figure out if this is some mysql setting or if I have incorrectly configured the database.

[image]

I'm accessing the database via java spring-data persistence jpa requests.

sql table entry code:

```
 use storage_app_schema;
CREATE TABLE `StorageItem` (
`DateStored` tinyblob,
`Image` tinyblob,
`Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`ReferenceCode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`Size` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL)
```

Comment: Are you using some automated tools to sync your schema? I once worked on project where one of the `mvn` commands dropped the current schema and re-created every time.

Comment: It occurs every time i redeploy - do you know what config causes this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto was set to "create". I wasn't aware this dropped existing table. This should be set to "update" - in order to update the existing schema as opposed to overriding it when the session closes.